# How to crawl a web site where page navigation involves dynamic loading

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl a website having multiple pages and when a page number is clicked it is dynamically loaded.How to screen scrape it?

i.e as the url is not present as href or a how to crawl to other pages?

Would be greatful if someone helped me on this.

PS:URL remains the same when different page is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider also [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), since it allows you tu run arbitrary javascript commands, fill forms and take snapshoot very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using google chrome, you can check the url which is dynamically being called in 
`network->headers`  of the developer tools

so based on that you can identify whether it is a `GET` or `POST` request.

If it is a `GET` request you can find the parameters straight away from the url.

If it is a `POST` request you can find the parameters from `form data` in `network->headers`
of the developer tools.

Comment: No get parameter used url remains the same.I suppose Ajax technique has been used

Comment: can you paste the url you are trying to crawl if possible?

Comment: :its www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphont

Comment: send a post request to http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/smartphone/productlist with the page and rows parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could look for the data you want in the javascript code instead of the HTML.  This is usually a pain but you can do fun things with regular expressions.

Alternatively, some of the browser testing libraries like [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) work by loading the page up in an actual browser like firefox or chrome before scraping.  One of those would work if you are running this on a machine with a browser installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post has been tagged with python and web-crawler, Beautiful Soup has to be mentioned: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Documentation here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download/2.x/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that easily since it is an ajax pagination (even with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)). Instead, open the source file of the page and try to know what is the url request used for  the ajax pagination. Then, you can create a fake request back and process the returned data by your own way

Comment: Can selenium library help me on this?

Comment: i never play with selenium before :(. You should try it then

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using gevent.[GRobot](https://github.com/DYFeng/GRobot) is another good choose.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.